# How to convert BLOB to DOUBLE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, casting, double

I have a BLOB column that stores 64-bit IEEE double-precision values and I would like to cast it to DOUBLE values. I'm working with MySQL 5.7.

For example, I have the HEX string 40053F7CED916872 that should cast to the DOUBLE value 2.656. I'm no MySQL guru and have researched CAST, CONV, CONVERT and other functions with no luck.

Somehow I feel I'm drowning in a glass of water, so I would really appreciate your insights.

Comment: Can you share with us why you want to do that?

Comment: @marekful, shure, thanks for asking. We have some binary software configuration files stored as BLOBs and I need to query a specific alarm value within that BLOB. I have identified the specific section where the 64-bit DOUBLE value resides but I'm stuck with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After diving deep in how DOUBLE numbers are stored, I finally came across a solution:

```
    SELECT 
POW(-1,CONV(SUBSTRING(LPAD(CONV('40053F7CED916872',16,2),64,'0'),1,1),2,10))*
POW(2,CONV(SUBSTRING(LPAD(CONV('40053F7CED916872',16,2),64,'0'),2,11),2,10)-1023)*
(1+CONV(SUBSTRING(LPAD(CONV('40053F7CED916872',16,2),64,'0'),13,52),2,10)/POW(2,52)) AS DBL;
```

The result:

```
+-------+
| DBL   |
+-------+
| 2.656 |
+-------+
```

Basically convert the BLOB to its binary representation, extract the subsections corresponding to sign, exponent and mantissa, convert them to integers and combine them to calculate the DOUBLE. Some references I used:

[online converter](https://gregstoll.com/~gregstoll/floattohex/)

[a tutorial](http://cstl-csm.semo.edu/xzhang/Class%20Folder/CS280/Workbook_HTML/FLOATING_tut.htm)

[more details](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~eedwards/compsys/float/)

Hope this could help someone else in the future. Regards.

Daniel

Comment: There's one catch. This doesn't work for a DOUBLE equal to zero, since that's handled as a special case. I don't need that, anyway, so it is enough for me.